# How to use mediaPlayer correctlty?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media

I'm trying to play music in my app and while the media player is loading I want to allow the user to keep on using the app, but the app gets stuck for few seconds every time I start loading the media player, and when the media player is finished loading, only then the app returns to normal and starts working again, sometimes it's not just freezing, it also shows popup menu from the OS that prompts the user to quit the app.

I couldn't find any solution in Google or YouTube, anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                    String STREAM_URL = #####;  // here i put the URL of the song
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: NullPointerException = " + e.getMessage());
                FirebaseCrash.log("Tag = " + TAG + "run: NullPointerException = " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
};
handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: share the logs please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are creating a `Handler`, the creation of the `MediaPlayer` still happens on the main UI thread. You should call `prepareAsync` or use an `AsyncTask` or some other means to avoid calling `prepare` on the main thread.

From the [documentation for `Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message
>   queue of the thread that is creating it

If you are streaming music from the network, preparing the media for playback is especially going to take a while. One option may be to call `prepareAsync` instead of calling `prepare`. In that case, you should set the [`OnPreparedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)), and in that callback call `start`.

Comment: I tried changing the prepare to prepareAsync and adding the prepareListener and start the media iside it and the app doesn't get stuck anymore but the music won't play either.. 
so you are saying that it is also posibble that i didn't create the handler currectly? what's the right way of creating the handler?

Comment: I don't think you need the `Handler` at all. And I am not saying you didn't create it properly. I just think it was not doing what you expected it to do. By creating a `Handler` and posting the `Runnable` to it, you are running that code on the same thread, just at a slightly later time when that thread's event loop handles that event you posted.

Comment: As far as the `MediaPlayer` not playing, please output some log in the `OnPreparedListener` to make sure it is being called and make sure there are no warnings or errors in the log. Your code in the question doesn't call `start`, so I'm not entirely sure how you were using it before.

Comment: I just solved the problem, Thank you so much Dave, you were really helpful. I was having this problem since day 1 of developing the app, finaly solved the problem... My mistake was changing the media controls (all the views buttons, etc..) outside of the PrepareListener, and only putting the mediaPlayer.start(); inside thist listener, so probably the reason that the app got stuck all the time is that the views were waiting for the media to load and only then they would update to the right info...
 Really man, TNX a lot :)

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: How can you listen for a "Track Changed" event? For example, if you have a label that displays the track name form the stream and you want to update it.